# How to design an algorithm to linear interpolate points in 3D space and create an indented surface?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, 3d

I am trying to develop a function that takes a matrix of input, out a contour plot as an output. There is a function in `matlab` which fits to my purpose. But for a self-examination method, I would like to do this myself. Like I said, my purpose is self-examination, I will not use this in an app or something.

Here is the deal, I have tried to do this with color maps, but what I got is a graph that seems like an uncalibrated TV channel:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yeniakit.com.tr](http://cdn.yeniakit.com.tr/images/news/625/televizyon-niye-karincalanir-h1425477874.jpg))</sub>

Graph is like that because, my function is discrete. I need to make this discreet function continuous.

I found a solution to this problem. Solution uses linear interpolation method to connect each point with each other. Surface created this way will have lots of rough edges but that is not a problem. Connecting the points in the space to create surfaces is OK, but those surfaces also has point on them. Computing such a thing would be very expensive, since a lot of computations involved. For example, lets say, I would like to create a surface by using 20x20 matrix. Rows and columns will be the x and y coordinates, values in each row and column will be the z coordinate.

I need to connect at least 3 dots to make a surface. Those surfaces have also points in them. I want to design such an algorithm that reduces the computations. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you wanting to do some sort of surface fitting, e.g. with the Curve Fitting toolbox? Or do you just want a `scatteredInterpolant` type solution?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the output image you're looking for?

Comment: Also, what function did you find in Matlab that does what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The `contour` function in matlab. Sample output is approximately like this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/examples/graphics/SpecifyNumberOfContourLinesExample_01.png  @nkjt yes it is like `scatteredInterpolant`